# ¿Cómo sumar dos o más filas adyacentes en una columna dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Tengo un archivo de excel el cual contiene una fecha con `15 minutos` de conteo y una precipitación, deseo con ello sumar las filas adyacentes en `p` para tener la lluvia acumulada para `30, 45, 60, 90 y 120` minutos, imploro respetuosamente con qué tipo de comando de pandas, podría hacer dicha operación, a continuación haré un ejemplo de que es lo que tengo y qué es lo que deseo:

Tengo:

```
      fecha         P
0   2001-02-02 18:45:00 0
1   2001-02-02 19:00:00 0
2   2001-02-02 19:15:00 0
3   2001-02-02 19:30:00 0
4   2001-02-02 19:45:00 0
5   2001-02-02 20:00:00 0
6   2001-02-02 20:15:00 0
7   2001-02-02 20:30:00 0
8   2001-02-02 20:45:00 0.25
9   2001-02-02 21:00:00 0
10  2001-02-02 21:15:00 0
11  2001-02-02 21:30:00 0
12  2001-02-02 21:45:00 0
13  2001-02-02 22:00:00 0
14  2001-02-02 22:15:00 0
15  2001-02-02 22:30:00 0
16  2001-02-02 22:45:00 1.27
17  2001-02-02 23:00:00 1.27
18  2001-02-02 23:15:00 0.....

558887 2017 12-31 23:45:00  22.8.....
```

Deseo:

```
Sumar fila 0 y fila 1 de la columna P
Sumar fila 2 y fila 3 de la columna P
Sumar fila 4 y fila 5 de la columna P
Sumar fila 6 y fila 7 de la columna P
```

Y luego obtener el valor máximo de dicha suma para cada año...

Comment: Bienvenido @Julian Andres Lastra Garcia a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No me encaja lo que quieres tener con la explicación que das de ello. Si sumas la fila 0 y 1, por ejemplo, tendrías la suma de las horas 18:45 y 19:00, que serían los datos acumulados de 30 minutos. Sumando las filas 2 y 3 sumarías las horas 19:15 y 19:30, que son otra vez 30 minutos. Por tanto no obtienes la "luvia acumulada para 30, 45, 60, 90 y 120 minutos" como dices en la descripción. Este tipo de acumulaciones no saldría de sumar filas de 2 en 2, sino de ir sumando 2, 3, 4, 6, y 8 filas, respectivamente.

Comment: Hola, es correcto lo que precisas, y así es tienes absoluta razón en lo que pido, lo que pasa que ese ejemplo que propuse sólo era para 30 minutos, mi duda es como puedo sumar esas filas y luego de ahí ubicar el resultado máximo para cada año; es decir para 45 minutos debería sumar las 3 filas adyacentes para 60 las 4 y así... espero aclarar dicha duda, lo que pasa es que con ello debo realizar unas curvas IDF con esos datos y preciso de hallar dichas duraciones... agradezco si puedes colaborarme con ello.